# How to browse a list with binary numbers

Tags: python

I have a list of 4 binary numbers and i want to check if they are divisible by 5, and if it's the case, i print them.

I've tried something but i'm stuck with an error, showing you the error and the code i made.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-8c92562788a5> in <module>()
      1 bin_liste = ['0100','0110','1010','1001']
      2 for element in bin_liste:
----> 3   if element%5 != 0:
      4     print(element)

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

my code:

```
bin_liste = ['0100','0110','1010','1001']
for element in bin_liste:
  if element%5 != 0:
    print(element
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the binary number as an integer value with the built-in `int()` function to use the modulus operator:

```
bin_liste = ['0100','0110','1010','1001']
for element in bin_liste:
  if int(element, 2)%5 != 0:
    print(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `element` is a binary string representation of an `int`, you need have an actual int to be able to apply arithmetic operations

```
bin_liste = ['0100', '0110', '1010', '1001']
for element in bin_liste:
    if int(element, 2) % 5 != 0:
        print(element, "-", int(element, 2))

0100 - 4
0110 - 6
1001 - 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bin_liste = ['0100','0110','1010','1001']
for element in bin_liste:
    if int(element, base=2) % 5:
        print(element)
```

You need to convert `str` elements in the list to numeric value.